# Custom Dictionary Encoder & Decoder for the Codable protocol in Swift 4

Tags: swift, dictionary, encoder, decoder, codable

If I have a struct that conforms to the `Codable` protocol like so:

```swift
enum AnimalType: String, Codable {
    case dog
    case cat
    case bird
    case hamster
}

struct Pet: Codable {
    var name: String
    var animalType: AnimalType
    var age: Int
    var ownerName: String
    var pastOwnerName: String?
}
```

How can I create an encoder & a decoder that encodes / decodes it to / from an instance of type `Dictionary<String, Any?>` like so?

```swift
let petDictionary: [String : Any?] = [
    "name": "Fido",
    "animalType": "dog",
    "age": 5,
    "ownerName": "Bob",
    "pastOwnerName": nil
]
let decoder = DictionaryDecoder()
let pet = try! decoder.decode(Pet.self, for: petDictionary)
```

**NB**: I'm aware that it's possible to use the `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` classes before casting the result to a dictionary object, but I don't want that for efficiency reasons.

The Swift standard library comes with the `JSONEncoder` and `JSONDecoder` as well as the `PListEncoder` and `PListDecoder` classes right out the box which conform to the `Encoder` and `Decoder` protocols respectively.

My problem is that I have no clue how to implement these protocols for my custom encoder and decoder classes:

```swift
class DictionaryEncoder: Encoder {

    var codingPath: [CodingKey]

    var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any]

    func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) -> KeyedEncodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey {

    }

    func unkeyedContainer() -> UnkeyedEncodingContainer {

    }

    func singleValueContainer() -> SingleValueEncodingContainer {

    }
}
```

```swift
class DictionaryDecoder: Decoder {

    var codingPath: [CodingKey]

    var userInfo: [CodingUserInfoKey : Any]

    func container<Key>(keyedBy type: Key.Type) throws -> KeyedDecodingContainer<Key> where Key : CodingKey {

    }

    func unkeyedContainer() throws -> UnkeyedDecodingContainer {

    }

    func singleValueContainer() throws -> SingleValueDecodingContainer {

    }
}
```

Given that Swift is open sourced, it's possible to view the source code of the [JSONEncoder](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift) and [PListEncoder](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/PlistEncoder.swift) classes in the standard library, but the source files are huge and difficult to understand due to the lack of documentation apart from a few comments.

Comment: If you don't want to use JSONDecoder then why implement the Codable protocols?

Comment: The Codable protocol is generalized / generic and can be used to represent external data structures with native Swift types. The Swift standard library has the `Encoder` and `Decoder` protocols which you can implement to create your own custom encoder & decoder for the Codable protocol.

The Swift standard library comes with two such Encoder / Decoder pairs:
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/PlistEncoder.swift
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift

Comment: My problem is that the code there is far too complex and apart from the comments in the code base there's no documentation that explains how you can implement your own custom encoder & decoder that conform to the `Encoder` and `Decoder` protocols respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of `JSONDecoder` ([here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/e5fdc0955ce662bd929c7e1706d4a1f1d0f5d397/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/JSONEncoder.swift#L1097)), you'll see that it's a two-step process: 1. use `JSONSerialization` to convert the `Data` into an json dictionary, then 2. create an instance of an internal class `_JSONDecoder` to do the dictionary -> `Codable` object conversion.

There is [some discussion on the Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org/t/jsondecoder-has-too-few-opportunities-need-an-enhancement/7020/3) on possibly exposing the internal types, and the Swift team may do something about it in the future.  Someone also offered up a 3rd party framework for doing what you want.